# Pasar String de un fichero json a html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A través de una consulta a una API, obtengo un texto que incluye etiquetas HTML. Este texto lo tengo que incluir en JSX dentro de un programa de React.js. El caso es que he intentado hacer uso de `document.write()` para poder pasar el String a etiquetas HTML, y lo hace, pero algo ocurre porque se queda eternamente pensando. De hecho, el resto de elementos que tengo como el header, el enlace, el título h1 y la imagen desaparecen.

La parte del render me quedaría así:

```
  render() {

        return (<div>
          <Header />
          <div className='main-wrapper'>
            <Router>
              <Link className='back-home' to="/">Ver todas las noticias</Link>
            </Router>
          {
            this.state.articles.map(articulo => {
              console.log(articulo.content.rendered)
              return (
                <article className='article-wrapper' key={articulo.id}>
                  <h1>{articulo.title.rendered}</h1>
                  <img className='article-image' src={articulo.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.small.source_url} />
                  <div className='article-content'>{document.write(articulo.content.rendered)}</div>
                </article>

              )
            })
          }
        </div>
        </div>)
    }
```

He probado sin embargo a hacer lo mismo cogiendo el texto y probarlo en un [editor](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_write), y ahí sí que funciona, aunque la imagen no carga.

Comment: Prueba con reemplazar el div por esto: `<div className='article-content' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: articulo.content.redered }}>`

Comment: @GermanAlzate gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he probado pero me lanza bastantes errores.

Comment: Lo que te dice @GermanAlzate es la forma en que la documentación dice que se debe meter código HTML en runtime. ¿Puedes decirnos qué errores ves?

Comment: Con `document.write` borras todo, porque estás referenciando al dom raíz de tu explorador y reescribiendo su contenido con `write`. Tal cual dicen otros comentarios, la manera correcta de agregar html en react es con `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, aunque si quisieras insistir probando con document (no recomendado), la manera correcta sería con `document.body.appendChild()`.